# I need to find all users home directories listed using grep from /etc/passwd

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a question similar to another one on this site where the individual had to find a list of all users using grep or awk from /etc/passwd. That worked for me but I've tried translating it to find and list the home directories of them also. I already know you can't do it in one line so I know I would use a pipeline. I've done my research online but I can't figure it out the problem is. If I use grep and do something like the following:

```
   grep -oE '^[/*/]$' /etc/passwd
```

...i t would probably give me an error or it will also show me the /bin/bash files which is not what I want. I just need the user names and their home directories listed using grep! I'm also not sure if the * will show other forward-slashes as characters, as some home directories have more than just two /'s (forward-slashes).

Comment: Also, `/etc/passwd` may or may not be where all the users are. Consider also `getent passwd`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grep is really not the tool for parsing out data this way;
grep is more for pattern matching and you're trying to do text-processing. 
You would want to use awk.

```
awk -F":" '$7 == "/bin/false" {print "User: "$1 "Home Dir: "$6}' /etc/passwd
```

- `awk` – The command
- `-F":"` – Sets the data delimiter to `:`
- `$7 == "/bin/false"` – Checks if the 7th data column is `/bin/false`
- `{print "User: "$1 "Home Dir: "$6}'` – Says to print the first column and sixth column in the specified format.
- `/etc/passwd` – Is the file we're processing

Comment: I'm not too fond of awk could you explain what the -F: and '{print $1" "$6}' do exactly?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your question

Comment: yeah see for me when i do that it still shows me the password encryptions, UID GIDS what type of shell we are using. I need it to just print the users and they're home directories, nothing else. using grep or awk of course.

Comment: when i use the following: `grep -oE '^[^:]+' /etc/passwd` that gives me just the users i need to pipline something like that or something similar to have the home directories there with them

Comment: Can we see a sample (obfuscated) line from your etc passwd? It doesn't sound like it's : delimited or if it is, it's not laid out normally.

Comment: so basically it will show me something like this as one of the lines and continue on: `1statd:x:116:65534::/var/libs/nfs:/bin/false` and i checked out the nano /etc/passwd and it is the exact same except without the 1 at the front of each line of each user

Comment: I added sample output. Are you sure you typed the command correctly?

Comment: yeah i don't know I'm looking at it exactly as it is those are not back ticks or anything right there single quotes and doubles and dollar signs it just doesn't give me the same output I've checked it char for char 6 times atleast and the F is supposed to be enlarged ofcourse and that's a colon between the quotes. is there any way we can do a grep form to get the home dir and I can pipline it with my initial grep command?

Comment: K i fugred it out alright so basically my dummyness always misses something I had it written like 1$ lol not $1 and it also asked me to get all the ones with the bins that are false which i added the line $7 so now my only problem is thi is what it looks like: `awk -F":" '{print "Users:"$1 "Home Dirs:"$6 "False Bins"$7} /etc/passwd` all i have to do now is get only the /bin/false records and write it into a file called users.txt

Comment: I updated the answer with your additional requirement to have the shell be /bin/false.

Comment: yeah can you check my other post if necessary and if I do that and add $7 in print will it only print the /bin/false? also how do i insert it into a file by after the `/etc/passwd > ExampleLab/users.txt` that which i already have made ofcourse the example labs the users.txt is new

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to split files with columns on a specific delimiter:

```
cut -d: -f6 /etc/passwd
```

Or `-f1,6` for columns (fields) 1 and 6.

Comment: Simple tools that do one job and do it well. Plus one!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `grep` isn't the best tool for this. If you insist on using it, and if your `grep` supports the `-o` (only print the matched portion of the line) and `-P` (use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions), you can do this:

```
$ grep -oP '^[^:]+|.*:\K[^:]+(?=:[^:]+)' /etc/password
terdon
/home/terdon
bob
/home/bob
```

<sup>Note that this will print all users, including system users. I am only showing 4 lines as an example.</sup>

That will print the user name and home directories of all users but on separate lines. You then need to join each pair of lines to get them together:

```
$ grep -oP '^[^:]+|.*:\K[^:]+(?=:[^:]+)' /etc/passwd | perl -pe 's/\n/ : / if $.%2'
root : /root
bin : /bin
daemon : /
mail : /var/spool/mail
ftp : /srv/ftp
http : /srv/http
uuidd : /
dbus : /
nobody : /
systemd-journal-gateway : /
systemd-timesync : /
systemd-network : /
systemd-bus-proxy : /
systemd-resolve : /
systemd-journal-upload : /
systemd-coredump : /
systemd-journal-remote : /
terdon : /home/terdon
avahi : /
polkitd : /
colord : /var/lib/colord
rtkit : /proc
gdm : /var/lib/gdm
git : /
bob : /home/bob
```

#### Explanation

The regex has two parts, it looks for `^[^:]+` OR (that's what the `|` means) `.*:\K[^:]+(?=:[^:]+)`. The first looks for one or more non-`:` characters from the beginning of the line. This matches the user name. The second part looks for as many characters as possible until a `:` (`.*:`) and then discards them (that's what the `\K` does) so they're not printed. It then matches a string of non-`:` which is followed by `:` and non-`:`. The `(?=foo)` construct is called a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and is a way of matching the characters *after* a pattern without including those characters in the match itself.

The `perl` command will replace newlines with `:` and spaces if the current line number (`$.`) is divisible by 2. So, every second line.

Comment: perl can do the whole job with 'awk-mode' `perl -naf: -e 'print $F[0]." : ".$F[5].$/'` so `sed 'N;s/\n/ : /'` might be a better partner for `grep -oP`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this with "cut", using just one binary, avoiding pipes, reaching the same results as the other answers, but  in a more elegant way :), like this:

```
$ cut -d : -f 1,6 /etc/passwd

root:/root
daemon:/usr/sbin
bin:/bin
sys:/dev
sync:/bin
games:/usr/games
man:/var/cache/man
lp:/var/spool/lpd
mail:/var/mail
news:/var/spool/news
....
```

If you wanna have an output better formatted + alphabetical order, here is, but the trade off is that, you have to use more binaries:

```
$ cut -d : -f 1,6 /etc/passwd | sort | column

avahi-autoipd:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd        man:/var/cache/man
avahi:/var/run/avahi-daemon                 messagebus:/var/run/dbus
backup:/var/backups                         news:/var/spool/news
bin:/bin                                    nobody:/nonexistent
clickpkg:/nonexistent                       ntp:/home/ntp
colord:/var/lib/colord                      proxy:/bin
daemon:/usr/sbin                            pulse:/var/run/pulse
dnsmasq:/var/lib/misc                       root:/root
games:/usr/games                            rtkit:/proc
gnats:/var/lib/gnats                        saned:/home/saned
hplip:/var/run/hplip                        speech-dispatcher:/var/run/speech-dispatcher
irc:/var/run/ircd                           sync:/bin
ivanleon:/home/ivanleon                     sys:/dev
kernoops:/                                  syslog:/home/syslog
libuuid:/var/lib/libuuid                    usbmux:/home/usbmux
lightdm:/var/lib/lightdm                    usermetrics:/var/lib/usermetrics
list:/var/list                              uucp:/var/spool/uucp
lp:/var/spool/lpd                           whoopsie:/nonexistent
lxc-dnsmasq:/var/lib/lxc                    www-data:/var/www
mail:/var/mail
```